# Cursor loop update Table by many values

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, database-cursor

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR contacts
   IS
        SELECT SUM (budget) AS budget
          FROM et_bp_gl_account a, et_bp_fact f
         WHERE     f.gl_account_id = a.gl_account_id
               AND total_flag = 0
      GROUP BY month_id, org_unit_id;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN contacts
   LOOP
      UPDATE et_bp_fact
         SET budget = r.budget
       WHERE gl_account_id IN (SELECT total_element
                                 FROM et_bp_gl_account g, et_bp_fact f
                                WHERE f.gl_account_id = g.gl_account_id);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I want to update the table `ET_BP_FACT` by many values example(25,50,75)
returned from Cursor but when i execute the table updated by (25,25,25)

I think there an issue in the loop

Comment: I think you need to use fetch: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `UPDATE`'s `WHERE` clause doesn't "reference" cursor's values. Something like this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR contacts
   IS
        SELECT month_id, org_unit_id,         --> include additional columns here ... 
               SUM (budget) AS budget
          FROM et_bp_gl_account a, et_bp_fact f
         WHERE     f.gl_account_id = a.gl_account_id
               AND total_flag = 0
      GROUP BY month_id, org_unit_id;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN contacts
   LOOP
      UPDATE et_bp_fact
         SET budget = r.budget
       WHERE gl_account_id IN 
         (SELECT total_element
          FROM et_bp_gl_account g, et_bp_fact f
          WHERE f.gl_account_id = g.gl_account_id
            --
            AND f.org_unit_id = r.org_unit_id   --> ... and reference them here ...
            AND g.month_id = r.month_id);
                                                --> ... or, possibly, here
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I'd suggest you to *always* precede column names with table aliases, because - looking at your code, there's no way to guess which table(s) `MONTH_ID` and `ORG_UNIT_ID` belong to, so my code might (or might not) work, but I hope you got the general idea.